# DataFrame is created for each index in loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, python-3.7

I am writing a script to take time series data. The idea is to only take the last timestamp and corresponding value and create a whole DataFrame, that contains the last 'ts' and 'value' in each entityId. However, we encountered a problem in our loop, which created a DataFrame for each row (as shown below), which is 120 DataFrames. This should ideally be 1 DataFrame.

**so this is the code:**

```
for i, ids in enumerate(data.id):
    URL2 = baseURL + "TimeValues" + "?entityId=" + ids
    timevalues = requests.get(URL2).json()
    df_timevalues = pd.DataFrame(timevalues)
    filtered_timevalues = df_timevalues.tail(1)
    print(filtered_timevalues)
```

**And the problem is this:**

```
                  ts         value
35  2020-04-07T08:15:15Z  23940.300781
                  ts         value
35  2020-04-07T08:45:15Z  10154.099609
                  ts         value
35  2020-04-07T08:49:44Z  7157.200195
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the received data to the existing dataframe:

```
filtered_timevalues = filtered_timevalues.append(
    df_timevalues, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: It didn't work. It gave the same output as df_timevalues, which gave all the timestamp and not the last one and it also created 120 different dataframe. But thanks anyway :D

Comment: Then you made a mistake somewhere else. But only if you're able to create a reproducable example, people will be able to help you! [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)